# What does underscore as an argument in C mean?

Tags: c, function, gcc, arguments

All modern compilers (clang 3.6, gcc 4.8) allow writing functions with an `_` in arguments' list.
Like this:

```
int func(_)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Even `main` allows such argument (`int main(_)`)

The only warning is

> p1_concat.c:31:5: warning: type of ‘_’ defaults to ‘int’ [enabled by default]

What does this underscore mean?

Comment: It's just a variable name, like any other.  The compiler doesn't treat it specially.  Sometimes people use it for variables whose value isn't used, but that's purely a convention and more common in other languages.  The warning is just what it says, and you'd see the same thing if you used any other name, e.g. `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underscore `_` is a valid, ordinary identifier. Defining a function like this:

```
type function(arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
    ...
}
```

(i.ee without parameter types) is a deprecated style back from the pre-ANSI days called a *K&R-style definition.* All parameters implicitly have type `int` unless you explicitly declare them to have a different type like this:

```
type function(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    type arg1;
    type arg2;
    type arg3;
{
    ...
}
```

where `type arg1;` is an ordinary declaration. These definitions are still allowed but deprecated. Because you didn't explicitly declare `_`, the compiler warns you about the implicit declaration as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int func(_)
{
    return 1;
}
```

is a function definition with an identifier list consisiting from one identifier with name `_` (underscore).

It is not a correct function definition. According to the C Standard (6.9.1 Function definitions)

> 6 If the declarator includes an identifier list, each declaration in
>   the declaration list shall have at least one declarator, those
>   declarators shall declare only identifiers from the identifier list,
>   **and every identifier in the identifier list shall be declared**.

It would be more correctly to define the function for example like

```
int func(_)
int _;
{
    return 1;
}
```

As for the similar definition of main

```
int main(_)
{
   //...
}
```

then it is not a valid declaration of main even if to add definition of the identifier `_` like it is done above

```
int main(_)
int _;
{
   //...
}
```

The C standard does not allow to declare main with an identifier list. At least it is not a standard declaration of main.

Comment: You should never write "K&R style" functions. It is an obsolescent feature as per 6.11.7.